# Spring Boot Jpa Update- Avoid unnecessary updates of columns & child entities

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a jpa entity with parent-child relationship(1:n).

Any sort of update on the entity results in jpa trying to update each and every column, even if there is no change in the value. I'm confused about the update behaviour for child enitities, I guess same would be happening with those also.

I went through `@DynamicUpdate` over entities but I do not know how they behave in case of child-entities.

```
public class Tutorial extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String title;

  private string description;

  @OneToMany(
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      mappedBy = "tutorial",
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      orphanRemoval = true)
  private Collection<Modules> Modules = new HashSet<>();

  // Getter/Setters

 }
```

How to come up with an approach so that only necessary fields/columns and child entities and their columns are update on each save.